# scalaz join operation requires type explicitly specified

Tags: scalaz

```
scala> Some(Some(9)) 
res23: Some[Some[Int]] = Some(Some(9))

scala> res23.join #plan a
<console>:24: error: value join is not a member of Some[Some[Int]]
          res23.join
                ^

scala> ((Some(Some(9))):Option[Option[Int]]).join #plan b
res25: Option[Int] = Some(9)
```

thought `plan a` should be equivalent to `plan b`. why the type has to be explicitly specified?

Not only this, I've seen other places that parameter type has to be explicitly spelled out. Thought scala could do type inference, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in your REPL :)

In the third line you declare an `Option[Option[Int]]` instead of a `Some[Some[Int]]` which is the type inferred in the first command.

Try:

```
scala> Option(Option(9)).join
res3: Option[Int] = Some(9)
```